# Python: Better solution to repeat function invocation in comprehension

Tags: python, xml, list, list-comprehension, elementtree

I have an XML file from which, I need to extract the ID and Title fields (under page tag). This is what I am doing, and it works fine. But, I am not happy with three calls to elem.find('title). Is there a better approach to avoid this with comprehensions? I understand that writing in a loop will solve this problem.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(some file)
root = tree.getroot()
id_title_list =  [(elem.find('id').text, elem.find('title').text)
                  for elem in root.findall('page')
                  if elem.find('title').text.startswith('string1') or
                     elem.find('title').text.startswith('string2')]
```

Comment: Are the three calls an issue, or is this a case of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) (the root of all evil)?

Comment: Instead of two calls to `startswith`, make one call with the tuple `('string1', 'string2')` as the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in breaking it down to a normal loop and having intermediate variables:

```
id_title_list = []
for elem in root.findall('page'):
    title = elem.find('title').text
    if title.startswith(('string1', 'string2')):
        id_title_list.append((elem.find('id').text, title))
```

Note that [`startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) supports multiple prefixes passed in as a tuple.

---

Another option would be to make `startswith()` checks inside the xpath expression:

```
id_title_list =  [(elem.find('id').text, elem.find('title').text)
                  for elem in root.xpath('//page[.//title[starts-with(., "string1") or starts-with(., "string2")])]']
```

Note that this would not work with `xml.etree.ElementTree` since it provides only limited support for xpath expressions. [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) would handle this, just change the import to:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
```

Comment: Yes please. Don't abuse list comprehensions when it isn't necessary. No one appreciates the simple for loop anymore.

Answer (score 1):

One way, respecting the request that this be solved with a comprehension:

```
id_title_list = [
    (elem.find('id').text, title)
        for elem, title in 
            (elem, elem.find('title').text for elem in root.findall('page'))
                if title.startswith(('string1', 'string2'))]
```

This uses an internal generator expression to evaluate the `find` only once per element. Because it's a lazily evaluated generator, it should avoid the overhead of an intermediate list. It also uses `startswith`'s ability to take a tuple of possible prefixes, although once you're only looking up the title text once that's more for concision than speed.

All that said, I agree with alexce's answer that a for loop is a better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

With some higher-order functions and itertools:

```
from operator import methodcaller
from itertools import tee, imap, izip

# Broken down into lots of small pieces; recombine as you see fit.

# Functions for calling various methods on objects
# Example: find_id(x) is the same as x.find('id')
find_id = methodcaller('find', 'id')
find_title = methodcaller('find', 'title')
is_valid = methodcaller('startswith', ('string1', 'string2'))
get_text = attrgetter('text')

found = root.findall('page')   # The original results...
found_iters = tee(found, 2)    # ... split into two.

# Make two iterators resulting from calling `find` on each element...
ids_iter = imap(get_text, imap(find_id, found_iters[0]))
titles_iter = imap(get_text, imap(find_title, found_iters[1]))

# And recombine them into a single iterable of tuples.
id_title_pairs = izip(ids_iter, titles_iter)

# Resulting in a nice, simple list comprehension
id_title_list = [(id, title) 
                   for id, title in id_title_pairs if is_valid(title)]
```